# How to call a splitmethod

Tags: python, split

Assume I have the data from a file called wordpop.txt:

```
Australia/AU/36/8177/22919  
Austria/AT/40/6936/8429
Azerbaijan/AZ/31/2896/9421
Bahamas/BS/44/79/351
```

I now want a stringmethod to divide each row at each "/" and I want to call the stringmethod. I know that I can use split like:

```
file=open("wordpop.txt","r")
rader = file.readlines()
for line in rader[5:]:
    line=line.split("/")
```

but how do I call it?

Comment: Uhm, you already called `.split('/')` in your example. What is your problem, exactly?

Comment: what's wrong with `line.split("/")`?

Comment: I mean have I called the stringmethod by just typing line.split("/")?

Comment: @John Yes. `line` is a string, `split` is a method of string objects. `()` after a callable (method or function) calls it. So yes, you have called a string method.

Comment: Why close? Why isn't this a valid question? Just because somebody is confused doesn't mean their question is invalid.

Comment: @poke Thank you, thats all I wanted

Comment: @orokusaki thanks for the support, I mean somehow one need to ask question without the question being classed as "stupid"

Answer (score 2):

I think your issue is that you are expecting the elements in `rader` to change when you do `line=line.split("/")`, but reassigning to `line` will not change the corresponding line in your list.  Try changing your loop to the following:

```
for i, line in enumerate(rader[5:], 5):
    rader[i] = line.split("/")
```

Comment: I mean have I called the stringmethod by just typing line.split("/")?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you need a list with the strings after the application of `split`.

I would also use `with` when handling the file and create another list for that, something like:

```
with open("wordpop.txt","r") as file:
    new_list = [line.split('/') for line in file.readlines()[5:]]
```